# sqlite : downloading a db

Tags: database, sqlite, download

I'm new android developer, first thank's for all the answers which helps me every day.
My question is:
I'm want to use a sqlite to have a db with many thousand rows but inserting this takes in average  one second per line :  it's too slow;
my db must be updated every day so I want to zip this db, downloading in a folder
of my application(assets ou raws).
Android sdk allows this? I look in many answers but i found nothing.
Thank's for all.
(excuse my English)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to [use transactions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html). You say `"BEGIN TRANSACTION"` to SQLite, then run all your `INSERT`s, then say `"COMMIT TRANSACTION"`. This is much faster because unless there's started transaction already SQLite runs every query inside a separate transaction (so-called autocommit) and doing `"COMMIT TRANSACTION"` internall for each `INSERT` is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

No idea about the android part, but inserts taking 1s is abnormal. If you're going to insert a large number of rows, do it in a transaction.

```
begin transaction;
insert into mytable values (...);
....
commit;
```

This will be *much* faster than just doing the inserts one at a time.